# Testing iOS Keyboard App Extension

Tags: ios, unit-testing, keyboard, xcode-ui-testing, ios-keyboard-extension

Is there any way to do Unit testing or UI testing of Keyboard App Extensions ?

It appears it was not possible in XCode6, but has Apple changed something in XCode 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking to Apple Developpers, the answer is no.
There is no way to do UITesting for Keyboard Extensions for now.

Answer (score -1):

I dont belive so, Apple is very serious about their pre-made stuff. Maybe look on their IOS Developer Libary and look for it. I Hope this helps

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry m8, I created an account here a few days ago as I didnt see much need in the past. I was just trying to help. Anyways thx for the advice.